# How to pipe large files through fold before opening?

Tags: shell, find-file, shell-command, performance

On a regular basis I need to open files that have really long lines, which unfortunately causes emacs to grind to a halt. My understanding is that this is a long-term issue with the renderer. I've tried disabling every possible mode, using every possible line wrapping package, etc. but none work well enough.

What I have found does work is first transforming the files in shell before opening them:

```
$ fold -w80 myfile > temp
```

Generally speaking I don't need to edit the files that have this property just view them, but it would still be convenient to look at them in emacs instead of going to `less` in the terminal. Is it possible to automate this and just have emacs do this every time I open a file that is sufficiently large or that has a sufficiently large first line?

Find file hooks look like they let me run code after the buffer is opened, but in this case I want to intercept the request to open the file and make it open the a synchronously arriving shell command output instead. Preferably in a way that will just work regardless of whether I open the file with helm, dired, etc.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/598/105

Answer (score 5):

#### Have emacs read from `stdin` device and insert contents into `*scratch*` buffer.

```
$ fold -w80 myfile | emacs --insert /path/to/stdin
```

> **Note:** You will need to update `/path/to/stdin` path

e.g.

```
$ fold -w80 myfile | emacs --insert /dev/stdin
```

---

> **This answer was validated using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1
>   This [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28630/is-there-some-way-to-continue-reading-from-a-stdin-file-descriptor-when-data-is) was used as a reference.

Comment: this works if you usually open files by using the command line, but I usually use ivy

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you are asking for, but perhaps a helpful step in the right direction: the command `shell-command`, bound to `M-!` by default, allows you to run a shell command from Emacs. If you call it with a prefix argument, the output from that command is inserted at point in the current buffer.

So, if you open a new buffer and invoke `C-u M-! fold -w80 ./path/to/myfile`, `myfile` will be wrapped at 80 columns and inserted in the new buffer.