# Org Mode Babel - Interactive code block evaluation in Python

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Similarly to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15065/org-mode-babel-interactive-code-block-evaluation) I would like to evaluate (in org mode) Python source code blocks containing "input" instructions but I can't find a way to have an interactive evaluation (with user input) during evaluation or to give it some input known in advance (stored in a file for instance).

My constraint is to use explicitly the `input` instruction since all this should be included in a textbook for students.

Example of code :

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output 
a= input("Value") 
print(a)
#+END_SRC
```

Is it possible to have such an interactive evaluation or to simulate it (by giving to the source code a fake input) ?

Comment: Will you be using org-mode `export` to generate your example code for the students into some other format, e.g. html?

Comment: Python's [input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) function only takes quoted text on single line, e.g. "hello" or "hi\nhello\nhowdy", correct?

Comment: @Melioratus Thaks for you comments; yes I use the org-mode export (to LaTeX/pdf) and I export both the code and the result.  You can also use multilines (""" ... """) text as a parameter for the input function. My problem is to introduce values to the "input" function during the execution of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll post an answer that uses the literate programming features , i.e. `noweb`, of org-mode that will allow you to test & export your code with results.

Comment: Thanks, this could be an alternative to the solution proposed by 
John Kitchin (may be avoiding the tangling step ?).

Comment: Correct you will not need to `tangle` any files unless you want to provide students your code samples as standalone scripts. Also you can choose if you want to be prompted for input when exporting by using elisp to ask you. I find creating and maintaining code examples as literate programs is much easier in the long term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that uses a non-exported, tangled file to replace the input function.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :exports none :tangle example1.py
def input(x): 
    if x == 'Value of a':
        return 3
    elif x == 'Value of b':
        return 4 

#+END_SRC 

#+RESULTS:
```

> **Tip:** Press <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-v</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> or use the <kbd>M-x</kbd><kbd>org-babel-tangle</kbd> command to create, i.e. [tangle](https://orgmode.org/manual/tangle.html), the `example1.py` file.

---

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :preamble from example1 import *
a = input('Value of a')
b = input('Value of b')
print(a + b) 
#+END_SRC 

#+RESULTS:
: 7
```

> **Note:** The `example1.py` file that was created from the previous python `SRC` block will be imported into the current block using the builtin [:preamble](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-python.html) header and the value `from example1 import *`.

Comment: Very interesting solution, thanks. I accept it as the solution and I will also propose a variant based on python generator and returning systematically a "str" object to mimic the input(...) function.

Answer (score 8):

## Evaluate `python` code blocks using literate programming in org-mode.

### Use `:var` header to assign variables and test your code.

> Note: If desired use `elisp` `(read-string "Prompt: ")` and `(read-number "Prompt: ")` to prompt for user input inside emacs.

---

#### Example 1 - *print(a)*

- Assign `hello world` to `a`.

  ---

  ```
  #+name: ex1-code  
  #+header: :var a="hello world"  
  #+begin_src python :results verbatim replace output :exports results  
    print(a)  
  #+end_src

  #+begin_src python :eval never :exports code :noweb yes   
    a = input('Value of a')  
    <<ex1-code>>  
  #+end_src  

  #+results: ex1-code
  : hello world
  ```

  ---

#### Example 2 - `print(a + b)`

- Assign `1` to `a`.
- Assign `2` to `b`.

  ---

  ```
  #+name: ex2-code
  #+header: :var a=1 
  #+header: :var b=2 
  #+begin_src python :results replace output  :exports results 
    print(a + b)
  #+end_src

  #+begin_src python :eval never :exports code :noweb yes 
    a = input('Value of a')
    b = input('Value of b')
    <<ex2-code>>
  #+end_src  

  #+results: ex2-code
  : 3
  ```

  ---

#### Example 3 - `print(a,b,c)`

- When prompted for `Value of a` enter `Thanks`
- When prompted for `Value of b` enter `4`.
- When prompted for `Value of c` enter `your question`.

  ---

  ```
  #+NAME: ex3-code
  #+header: :var a=(read-string "Value of a ") 
  #+header: :var b=(read-number "Value of b ") 
  #+header: :var c=(read-string "Value of c ") 
  #+begin_src python :results replace output   :exports results 
    print a,b,c
  #+end_src  

  #+begin_src python :eval never :exports code :noweb yes 
    a = input('Value of a')
    b = input('Value of b')
    c = input('Value of c')
    <<ex3-code>>
  #+end_src  

  #+results: ex3-code
  : Thanks 4 your question
  ```

  ---

> When you export your org file, the output should look similar to the example below

---

Example 1 - `print(a)`

- Assign `hello world` to `a`.

  ```
  a = input('Value of a')
  print(a)

  hello world
  ```

Example 2 - `print(a + b)`

- Assign `1` to `a`.
- Assign `2` to `b`.

  ```
  a = input('Value of a')
  b = input('Value of b')
  print(a + b)

  3
  ```

Example 3 - `print(a,b,c)`

- When prompted for `Value of a` enter `Thanks`
- When prompted for `Value of b` enter `4`.
- When prompted for `Value of c` enter `your question`.

  ```
  a = input('Value of a')
  b = input('Value of b')
  c = input('Value of c')
  print a,b,c

  Thanks 4 your question
  ```

---

---

> This code was tested with
>   GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.14.13)
>   Org-Mode Version: 8.3.2
>   and github.

Comment: Very interesting solution; it took time for me to understand (I'm not used to literate programming) that the instructions in the second python source bloc (e.g. a = input('Value of a')) were only documentation text and were not treated as instructions.

Comment: @Lgen - Thanks! The literate programming, `noweb`, in org-mode features are amazing and incredibly useful! Please let me know if you would like additional code examples. If you need something that doesn't fit well into the Q&A format, I'm happy to post to my GitHub repository.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is possible to get truly interactive Python input with org-babel.

You could use a preamble to redefine the input function so it returns what you want to simulate the use of input, e.g. here we make it look like the user typed in "3".

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :preamble def input(x): return 3
a = input("value ")
print(a)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 3
```

Depending on what students see that is exported, they might not see that you have done this.

Comment: Thanks John for you proposed answer. I was wondering if it is possible to extend it to a multiple call to the input function in the code block  (e.g. a=input("Value of a") b=input("Value of b")). To build the texbook I generally use and ":export both" in the "#+BEGIN_SRC python" statement so this line should not be visible in the exported text.

Comment: If you use a session, it is possible:

#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :exports none
def input(x):
    if x == 'Value of a':
        return 3
    elif x == 'Value of b':
        return 4
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :session
a = input('Value of a')
b = input('Value of b')

print(a + b)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: 
: >>> >>> 7

Answer (score 2):

As a complement of John Kitchin's solution, I propose to use a generator to provide the successive values that will "feed" the `input(...)` functions and to return a `str`object systematically.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session :exports none :tangle example2.py :results none
def generate(lst):
    for element in lst:
        yield str(element)

generator =  generate(["Thanks",4,"your help"])

def input(x):
     return generator.__next__()
#+END_SRC 


#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :preamble from example2 import * :exports both
a = input('Value of a')
b = input('Value of b')
c = input('Value of c')
print(a,b,c)
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use tkinter and to input the value in an external window:

```
#+name: tkinput
#+begin_src python :results output :exports none
from tkinter.simpledialog import askstring
from tkinter import Tk

def input(message):
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    entered = askstring("", message)
    root.destroy()
    return entered
#+end_src

#+name: test-tkinput
#+begin_src python :results output :exports code :noweb strip-export
<<tkinput>>
x = input("Test1")
y = input("Test2")
print(x,y)
#+end_src
```